# Aggregation results cannot properly map to Java object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get schedules data from mongoDb. 
I created the appropriate aggregation and tried to convert it within Spring Framework.

```
db.theaters.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'city_id': <someCityId>, 'theatreRooms.schedules.spectacle_id': <someSpecId> } }, 
    { $unwind: '$theatreRooms' },
    { $unwind: '$theatreRooms.schedules' },
    { $group: { _id: { name: '$name', room: '$theatreRooms.name' }, schedules: { $addToSet: '$theatreRooms.schedules.time' } } },
    { $group: { _id: '$_id.name', schedules: { $addToSet: { room: '$_id.room', schedules: '$schedules' } } } }
])
```

I've created properly match and unwind operations. But I've got problem with first group operation. 
It seems that the operation is well interpreted, but for some reason I am not able to properly map the _id object.

Here is my code example:

```java
public class TheaterProject {

    private TheaterId _id;
    private List<String> schedules;

    public TheaterId get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(TheaterId _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public List<String> getSchedules() {
        return schedules;
    }

    public void setSchedules(List<String> schedules) {
        this.schedules = schedules;
    }
}
```

```java
public class TheaterId {

    @Field("name")
    private String name;

    @Field("room")
    private Integer room;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(Integer room) {
        this.room = room;
    }
}
```

```java
public Document  getRawSchedules(String cityId, String spectaclesId){
        MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("city_id").is(cityId).and("theatreRooms.schedules.spectacle_id").is(spectaclesId));
        UnwindOperation theaterUnwind = Aggregation.unwind("theatreRooms");
        UnwindOperation schedulesUnwind = Aggregation.unwind("theatreRooms.schedules");

        GroupOperation firstGroup = Aggregation.group(Fields.from(
                Fields.field("name", "name"),
                Fields.field("room", "theatreRooms.name")))
                .addToSet("theatreRooms.schedules.time").as("schedules");

        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match,theaterUnwind,schedulesUnwind,firstGroup);
        Document theaters = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Theater.class, TheaterProject.class).getRawResults();
        return theaters;
    }
```

```java
public List<TheaterProject>  getSchedules(String cityId, String spectaclesId){
        MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("city_id").is(cityId).and("theatreRooms.schedules.spectacle_id").is(spectaclesId));
        UnwindOperation theaterUnwind = Aggregation.unwind("theatreRooms");
        UnwindOperation schedulesUnwind = Aggregation.unwind("theatreRooms.schedules");

        GroupOperation firstGroup = Aggregation.group(Fields.from(
                Fields.field("name", "name"),
                Fields.field("room", "theatreRooms.name")))
                .addToSet("theatreRooms.schedules.time").as("schedules");

        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match,theaterUnwind,schedulesUnwind,firstGroup);

        List<TheaterProject> theaters = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Theater.class, TheaterProject.class).getMappedResults();
        return theaters;
    }
```

When I've invoked method getSchedules which return mapped objects, _id field is equal to null.

```
[
    {
        "_id": null,
        "schedules": [
            "5:15"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": null,
        "schedules": [
            "6:55",
            "4:35",
            "10:15"
        ]
    }
]
```

But when I've invoked getRawSchedules which used getRawResults it's looking properly.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "name": "Pinokio",
                "room": 2
            },
            "schedules": [
                "5:15"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "name": "Roma",
                "room": 1
            },
            "schedules": [
                "6:55",
                "4:35",
                "10:15"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't have any idea why it's working like that.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any information about this problem in the documentation and here. But I have a solution. You may just rename the field from `_id` to something else.  `theaterId` for example. I don't know all requirements for your issue but you may do it just on mapping level.

Fix the mapping

```java
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

import java.util.List;

public class TheaterProject {

    @Field("theaterId")
    private TheaterId _id;
    private List<String> schedules;

    public TheaterId get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(TheaterId _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public List<String> getSchedules() {
        return schedules;
    }

    public void setSchedules(List<String> schedules) {
        this.schedules = schedules;
    }
}
```

But it requires additional projection step

```java
public List<TheaterProject>  getSchedules(String cityId, String spectaclesId){
    ...

    GroupOperation firstGroup = Aggregation.group(Fields.from(
                Fields.field("name", "name"),
                Fields.field("room", "theatreRooms.name")))
                .addToSet("theatreRooms.schedules.time").as("schedules");

    ProjectionOperation projection = Aggregation.project(Fields.from(
                Fields.field("theaterId", "_id"),
                Fields.field("schedules", "schedules")));

    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation( ... ,firstGroup, projection);

    List<TheaterProject> theaters = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "collectionName", TheaterProject.class).getMappedResults();
    return theaters;
}
```